# Aurelio fetch infinite loop

Tags: asp.net, aurelia

I'm working on my first Aurelia app with the skeleton for typescript+asp.net core. However, the fetch operation is going into an infinite loop and I dont know why.
/api/Hierarchy/Tree?id=0 keeps getting requested infnitely. However there is no use of id=0 and I dont know why it would request anything more than once on activation of the view.

Tree.ts

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import 'fetch';

@autoinject
export class Tree {
    heading = 'Tree';
    Tree = [];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        http.configure(config => {
            config
                .useStandardConfiguration()
                .withBaseUrl('/');
        });
    }

    update(id: string)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            id = "1";        
        }

        return this.http.fetch('api/Hierarchy/Tree?id=' + id)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(Tree => this.Tree = Tree);
    }

    activate() {
        return this.http.fetch('api/Hierarchy/Tree?id=1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(Tree => this.Tree = Tree);
    }
}
```

Tree.html

```
<template>
    <div class="messageHierarchy-wrapper">
        <div class="message parents">
            <h4 class="parent" click.bind="update(Tree.parent.id)" value.bind="Tree.parent.id"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="message current">
            <h4 class="current" value.bind="Tree.current.id"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="message children">
            <h4 class="child" repeat.for="aChild of Tree.children" click.bind="update(aChild.id)" value.bind="aChild.id">

            </h4>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HierarchyController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        // GET: Hierarchy/Tree/5
        public IActionResult Tree(int id)
        {
            List<MessageViewModel> _items = new List<MessageViewModel>()
            {
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=1, CorrelationID=1, PreCorrelationID = 1 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=2, CorrelationID=2, PreCorrelationID = 1 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=3, CorrelationID=3, PreCorrelationID = 2 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=4, CorrelationID=4, PreCorrelationID = 2 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=5, CorrelationID=5, PreCorrelationID = 2 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=6, CorrelationID=6, PreCorrelationID = 3 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=7, CorrelationID=7, PreCorrelationID = 3 }
            };

            MessageHierarchyViewModel aTree = new MessageHierarchyViewModel();
            MessageViewModel aCurrentItem = _items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CorrelationID == id);
            aTree.Current = aCurrentItem;

            if (aCurrentItem != null)
            {
                aTree.Parent = _items.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CorrelationID == aCurrentItem.PreCorrelationID);
            }
            else
            {
                aTree.Parent = _items.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CorrelationID == 1);
            }

            aTree.Children = _items.Where(x => x.PreCorrelationID == id).ToList();

            return Ok(aTree);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through each request to understand where values are coming from?

Comment: Also, you should probably use `${Tree.parent.id}` inside the `<h4></h4>` instead of doing `value.bind`. It will read a lot better

Comment: This is my first project with asp.net core, typescript, gulp, aurelia etc. I have a few other issues besides the infinite loop which I'm trying to resolve: gulp serve stops after a fews seconds. Running the app with iisexpress I get empty typescript files so I cant see what I'm debugging..

Comment: super wild guess: rename update() - method to test() or so.
if its successful i'll try to explain :)

Comment: I'm a little closer because I changed the update method and changed the template to the correct aerelia syntax, like you guys said. I'm seeing the values now only the MVC controller is not yet receiving the id of the clicked element, must be a routing thing...

Comment: Need to make controller method declaration like this  public IActionResult Tree([FromQuery]int id). Asp.net core does not by default get parameters from query string anymore..

Answer (score 1):

Working like this:

Tree.ts

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import 'fetch';

@autoinject
export class Tree {
    heading = 'Tree';
    mainTree = [];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        http.configure(config => {
            config
                .useStandardConfiguration()
                .withBaseUrl('/');
        });
    }

    getTree(id: string)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            id = "1";        
        }

        return this.http.fetch('api/Hierarchy/Tree?id=' + id)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(aTree => this.mainTree = aTree);
    }

    activate() {
        return this.http.fetch('api/Hierarchy/Tree?id=1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(aTree => this.mainTree = aTree);
    }
}
```

Tree.html

```
<template>
    <div class="messageHierarchy-wrapper">
        <h2>${heading}</h2>
        <div class="message parents">
            <h4 class="parent" click.delegate="getTree(mainTree.parent.id)">${mainTree.parent.id}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="message current">
            <h4 class="current">${mainTree.current.id}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="message children">
            <h4 repeat.for="aChild of mainTree.children" click.delegate="getTree(aChild.id)">
                ${aChild.id}
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HierarchyController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        // GET: Hierarchy/Tree/5
        public IActionResult Tree([FromQuery]int id)
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                id = 1;
            }

            List<MessageViewModel> _items = new List<MessageViewModel>()
            {
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=1, CorrelationID=1, PreCorrelationID = 1 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=2, CorrelationID=2, PreCorrelationID = 1 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=3, CorrelationID=3, PreCorrelationID = 2 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=4, CorrelationID=4, PreCorrelationID = 2 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=5, CorrelationID=5, PreCorrelationID = 2 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=6, CorrelationID=6, PreCorrelationID = 3 },
                new MessageViewModel() { ID=7, CorrelationID=7, PreCorrelationID = 3 }
            };

            MessageHierarchyViewModel aTree = new MessageHierarchyViewModel();
            MessageViewModel aCurrentItem = _items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CorrelationID == id);
            aTree.Current = aCurrentItem;

            if (aCurrentItem != null)
            {
                aTree.Parent = _items.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CorrelationID == aCurrentItem.PreCorrelationID);
            }
            else
            {
                aTree.Parent = _items.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CorrelationID == 1);
            }

            aTree.Children = _items.Where(x => x.PreCorrelationID == id).ToList();

            return Ok(aTree);
        }
```